# no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to follow [GitHub - kubernetes/dashboard: General-purpose web UI for Kubernetes clusters](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started).

deploy/access:

```
# export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
# kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
# kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

curl:

```
# curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}#
```

Please advise.

per @VKR

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces 
NAMESPACE     NAME                                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-56vg7                          0/1     ContainerCreating   0          57m
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-sn2fk                          0/1     ContainerCreating   0          57m
kube-system   etcd-wcmisdlin02.uftwf.local                      1/1     Running             0          56m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-wcmisdlin02.uftwf.local            1/1     Running             0          56m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-wcmisdlin02.uftwf.local   1/1     Running             0          56m
kube-system   kube-proxy-2hhf7                                  1/1     Running             0          6m57s
kube-system   kube-proxy-lzfcx                                  1/1     Running             0          7m35s
kube-system   kube-proxy-rndhm                                  1/1     Running             0          57m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-wcmisdlin02.uftwf.local            1/1     Running             0          56m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-g2hts             0/1     Pending             0          2m38s
$
```

`logs`:

```
$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-g2hts -n kube-system
$
```

`describe`:

```
$ kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-g2hts -n kube-system
Name:               kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-g2hts
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
                    pod-template-hash=77fd78f978
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978
Containers:
  kubernetes-dashboard:
    Image:      k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.0
    Port:       8443/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Args:
      --auto-generate-certificates
    Liveness:     http-get https://:8443/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /certs from kubernetes-dashboard-certs (rw)
      /tmp from tmp-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kubernetes-dashboard-token-gp4l7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  kubernetes-dashboard-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kubernetes-dashboard-certs
    Optional:    false
  tmp-volume:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  
  kubernetes-dashboard-token-gp4l7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kubernetes-dashboard-token-gp4l7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                      From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                     ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m39s (x21689 over 20h)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
$
```

Comment: Provide `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces' output. Is your kubernetes-dashboard-... in the CrashLoopBackOff state?

Comment: Do a kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-g2hts to see why its not getting ready.

Comment: For both your kubectl logs and kubectl describe pod commands you need to add the namespace as the pod is not in the default namespace. Like this: kubectl -n kube-system ...

Comment: @VKR in my dev environment, `STATUS` of `coredns` is between `Error` and/or `CrashLoopBackOff`. Please advise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would appear that you are attempting to deploy Kubernetes leveraging `kubeadm` but have skipped the step of [Installing a pod network add-on (CNI)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network). Notice the warning:

> The network must be deployed before any applications. Also, CoreDNS will not start up before a network is installed. kubeadm only supports Container Network Interface (CNI) based networks (and does not support kubenet).

Once you do this, the CoreDNS pods should come up healthy. This can be verified with:
`kubectl -n kube-system -l=k8s-app=kube-dns get pods`

Then the `kubernetes-dashboard` pod should come up healthy as well.

Comment: That is not a solution to the question. In my case the coredns runs fine, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 8):

you could refer to https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started

Also, I see "https" in your link
Please try this link instead
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Answer (score 7):

if you are using `helm`,

check if `kubectl proxy` is running

then goto

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy

two tips in above link:

1. use `helm` to install, the namespaces will be `/default` (not `/kubernetes-dashboard`
2. need add `https` after `/https:kubernetes-dashboard:`

better way is

`helm delete kubernetes-dashboard`

`kubectl create namespace kubernetes-dashboard`

`helm install -n kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard`

then goto

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy

then you can easily follow [creating-sample-user](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md) to get token to login

Comment: This second `https` is missing from every tutorial I came across, like [this one from k3s](https://docs.k3s.io/installation/kube-dashboard). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In the end it turned out as a Calico Network configuration problem. But step by step...

First I checked if the Dashboard Pod was running:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

The result for me was:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-bcc6f659f-j57l9      1/1     Running            2          19h
kube-system            calico-node-hdxp6                            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         15h
kube-system            calico-node-z6l56                            0/1     Running            68         19h
kube-system            coredns-74ff55c5b-8l6m6                      1/1     Running            2          19h
kube-system            coredns-74ff55c5b-v7pkc                      1/1     Running            2          19h
kube-system            etcd-got-virtualbox                          1/1     Running            3          19h
kube-system            kube-apiserver-got-virtualbox                1/1     Running            3          19h
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-got-virtualbox       1/1     Running            3          19h
kube-system            kube-proxy-q99s5                             1/1     Running            2          19h
kube-system            kube-proxy-vrpcd                             1/1     Running            1          15h
kube-system            kube-scheduler-got-virtualbox                1/1     Running            2          19h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b59f7d4df-qc9ms   1/1     Running            0          28m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-zrdk4        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          28m
```

The last line indicates, that the dashboard pod could not have been started (status=CrashLoopBackOff).
And the 2nd line shows that the calico node has problems. Most likely the root cause is Calico.

Next step is to have a look at the pod log *(change namespace / name as listed in YOUR pods list)*:

```
kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-zrdk4 -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

The result for me was:

```
2021/03/05 13:01:12 Starting overwatch
2021/03/05 13:01:12 Using namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
2021/03/05 13:01:12 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2021/03/05 13:01:12 Using secret token for csrf signing
2021/03/05 13:01:12 Initializing csrf token from kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret
panic: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Hm - not really helpful. After searching for "dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout" I found this information, where it says ...

> If you follow the kubeadm instructions to the letter ... Which means install docker, kubernetes (kubeadm, kubectl, & kubelet), and calico with the Kubeadm hosted instructions ... and your computer nodes have a physical ip address in the range of 192.168.X.X then you will end up with the above mentioned non-working dashboard. This is because the node ip addresses clash with the internal calico ip addresses.

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/1578#issuecomment-329904648

**Yes, in deed I do have a physical IP in the range of 192.168.x.x** - like many others might have as well. I wish Calico would check this during setup.

**So let's move the pod network to a different IP range:**

You should use a [classless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) reserved IP range for Private Networks like
10.0.0.0/8 (16.777.216 addresses)
172.16.0.0/12 (1.048.576 addresses)
192.168.0.0/16 (65.536 addresses). Otherwise Calico will terminate with an error saying "Invalid CIDR specified in CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR" ...

```
sudo kubeadm reset
sudo rm /etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist
sudo rm /etc/cni/net.d/calico-kubeconfig

export CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR=172.16.0.0
export MASTER_IP=192.168.100.122
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=$CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR/12 --apiserver-advertise-address=$MASTER_IP --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=$MASTER_IP

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo rm -f $HOME/.kube/config
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf

wget https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml -O calico.yaml
sudo sed -i "s/192.168.0.0\/16/$CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR\/12/g" calico.yaml
sudo sed -i "s/192.168.0.0/$CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR/g" calico.yaml
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

Now we test if all calico pods are running:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-bcc6f659f-ns7kz   1/1     Running   0          15m
kube-system   calico-node-htvdv                         1/1     Running   6          15m
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-lqwpd                   1/1     Running   0          17m
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-qzc87                   1/1     Running   0          17m
kube-system   etcd-got-virtualbox                       1/1     Running   0          17m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-got-virtualbox             1/1     Running   0          17m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-got-virtualbox    1/1     Running   0          18m
kube-system   kube-proxy-6xr5j                          1/1     Running   0          17m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-got-virtualbox             1/1     Running   0          17m
```

Looks good. If not check CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR by editing the node config: `KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit -n kube-system ds calico-node`

Let's apply the kubernetes-dashboard and start the proxy:

```
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
kubectl proxy
```

Now I can load http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same issue, so i followed the official docs and then went to https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard url, there is another way using helm on this link https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard

after installing helm and run this 2 commands

```
helm repo add kubernetes-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/

helm install kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard
```

it worked **but** on default namespace on this link
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy/#/workloads?namespace=default

Comment: That URL worked for me except the namespace was kubernetes-dashboard. Like this: `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy/#/login`