# How to restart a kubernetes-pod stuck in pending state?

Tags: kubernetes-pod

I'm setting up a Kubernetes master node. ***Just the master node, no worker nodes for now.***

Set up was completed without any issues using [this tutorial.](https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu) Now,

```
$kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-694687c474-96b7h   0/1     Pending   0          4h19m   <none>          <none>             <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-dv847                   0/1     Pending   0          4h28m   <none>          <none>             <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-pqvxv                   0/1     Pending   0          4h28m   <none>          <none>             <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-ip-172-31-40-128                      1/1     Running   0          4h28m   172.31.40.128   ip-172-31-40-128   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-40-128            1/1     Running   0          4h28m   172.31.40.128   ip-172-31-40-128   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-40-128   1/1     Running   0          4h28m   172.31.40.128   ip-172-31-40-128   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-zvgcl                           1/1     Running   0          4h28m   172.31.40.128   ip-172-31-40-128   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-40-128            1/1     Running   0          4h27m   172.31.40.128   ip-172-31-40-128   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-wlv86       0/1     Pending   0          3h55m   <none>          <none>
```

When I try to open the Kubernetes-dashboard using,
    http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ in local browser, it fails to open the dashboard and I receive below error in the browser:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

I assume as the kubernetes-dashboard pod is pending, dashboard would not open. How do I get it to work for me?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://faun.pub/how-to-restart-kubernetes-pod-7c702ca984c1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-wlv86` and the output should tell you why the Pod couldn't be scheduled. There can be different reasons and [kubernetes 'debug pods' guide covers several of them](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#my-pod-stays-pending). The most common is insufficient resources but it could be other things, especially on a new cluster. I notice the DNS pods are also pending - I'd suggest looking at those first as you [need networking to run applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893111/no-endpoints-available-for-service-kubernetes-dashboard).

Comment: Perfect! I needed to install pod network add-on. All pods in running state now. Thanks!