# Unable to access Kubernetes Dashboard panel (503 no endpoints available)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a problem with putting up kubernetes dashboard. It looks like it is only reaching pending status. I found information at events about the problem with freeing memory due to other images in the docker. I am looking for a solution, I cannot close the current images.

output:

```json
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

pods:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system            coredns-f9fd979d6-74xm2                      0/1     Pending   0          152m
kube-system            coredns-f9fd979d6-q68rg                      0/1     Pending   0          152m
kube-system            etcd-worker01                                1/1     Running   0          152m
kube-system            kube-apiserver-worker01                      1/1     Running   0          152m
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-worker01             1/1     Running   0          152m
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-xhv8x                        1/1     Running   0          151m
kube-system            kube-proxy-htxxg                             1/1     Running   0          152m
kube-system            kube-scheduler-worker01                      1/1     Running   0          152m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b59f7d4df-b9s6s   0/1     Pending   0          131m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-665f4c5ff-md882         0/1     Pending   0          95m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-rxh4w        0/1     Pending   0          131m
```

events:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                 OBJECT          MESSAGE
7m54s       Warning   EvictionThresholdMet   node/worker01   Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
2m52s       Warning   ImageGCFailed          node/worker01   (combined from similar events): wanted to free 29893186355 bytes, but freed 0 bytes space with errors in image deletion: [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete b4e0de857ea7 (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container 691fa8251b60, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 172a9481468c (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container b9e69a358748,...
```

logs are empty.

Answer (score 2):

Grant access to the dashbord by executing this URL:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy/
```

Notice this part:

```
/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/
```

Without adding the https it didn't work - you will always got `no endpoints available for service kubernetes-dashboard`.

See working link in the readme here: [kubernetes-dashboard-issue-endpoints](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kubernetes-dashboard).

Take a look: [dashboard-endpoints-issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/916)[endpoints-available-for-service-kubernetes-dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893111/no-endpoints-available-for-service-kubernetes-dashboard), [dashboard-endpoints](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/971), [kubernetes-503-no-endpoints-available](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/kubernetes-503-no-endpoints-available-for-service-the-cause-and-solution/).

Answer (score 2):

@PKosiba, no that's not a disc problem, this basically mean you have what's called taints and tolerations on the nodes/machines in your cluster, which in turn means that Kubernetes scheduler was not able to schedule your pod on any of the existing nodes because it doesn't have the corresponding taint, basically you have something on your nodes that say "do not schedule anything on this node that do not have this tag disk-pressure":

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/